# How to get file name from download link in firebase storage(Javascript, React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I've being trying to get files name from Firebase storage.
Right now I got a download link and trying to get name from it.

```
const showPhoto = () => {
        var eventDOM = event.target;
        var src = eventDOM.getAttribute('src');
        setpickImage(src);
        console.log(src);
        // src = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b....."
}
```

[image]

I need file name to delete file from storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to map a download URL back to a file name, use the [`refFromURL` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#reffromurl).

Also see the documentation on [creating a reference from a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#create_a_reference), which contains this example:

> ```
> var httpsReference = storage.refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg');
> ```

From that [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) you can then get other properties like [the file's name](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#name).

```
let fileName = httpsReference.name;
```

Comment: You've been a great help :) Thank you!!

Comment: Note: file name with %{}# characters will be chopped right before the %. Ex: abc%def.jpg will show abc. Security rules also don't work.

Answer (score 0):

> To get the file name and url or download link of the videos or files from the firebase storage you can use these two functions in javascript and react

```js
// function to fetch videos / files from firebase storage
const fetchVideos = async() => {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("your storage folder name");

  const videos = [];
  await storageRef
    .listAll()
    .then(async function(result) {

      result.items.forEach(async function(videoRef) {

        // getting the name of the file
        const videoName = videoRef.name;

        // getting the url of the file -> calling another function for this
       const videoUrl = await getVideoUrl(videoRef);

        // creating the object with name and url
        const videoObj = {
          videoName,
          videoUrl,
        };

        console.log("video obj", videoObj);
        videos.push(videoObj);
        
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Handle any errors
      return [];
    });
}

// function to get download url 
const getVideoUrl = (imageRef) => {
  const videoLink = imageRef
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then(function(videoUrl) {
      console.log("videoUrl", videoUrl);
      return videoUrl;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Handle any errors
      return "";
    });
  return videoLink;
};
```